# Can a Substring of innerHTML Be Extracted Upon Initial Invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As far as I can tell from the spec, the default (or only?) behavior of innerHTML's invocation is to capture all characters within the parent element.

So, for this HTML:

```
<div id="kirk">Gentlemen, I suggest you beam me aboard.</div>
```

This Javascript alert:

```
var thisHTML = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML;
alert('"' + thisHTML + '"');
```

Will display:

```
"Gentlemen, I suggest you beam me aboard."
```

To avoid the inefficient approach of first collecting all the innerHTML into an array and then manipulating the array to extract "men", is it possible to extract a substring of innerHTML right up front using (A) a (start index position,length) paradigm like this:

```
var thisHTML = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML(6,3);
```

or (B) using a (start index position,end index position) paradigm, like this:

```
var thisHTML = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML(6,8);
```

If the above does not exist, is there a way to code the equivalent?

Comment: you can split the inner html by "men" word. then you check if the word splitted, then it contains the "men" word, if not, then it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `innerHTML` is a string, not a function. You cannot invoke strings with round parentheses as you can invoke functions. There is no array involved in `document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML.substr(6, 3)` or `document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML.substring(6, 9)`, and those are the most efficient way to code what you tried to do in your OP.

Comment: I should have realized that innerHTML is an object. Thanks.

Comment: It is not an object. It is a string. Or rather, it is an object inasmuch as anything (except for `null` and `undefined`) is an object in JavaScript, but it is not *object* (as in, something distinct from strings, numbers, booleans... constructed by `new` or by literal `{ ... }` syntax). While strings are also objects in JavaScript in the former sense, calling them objects is confusing (as then there is no way to refer to things like  `{ a: 1 }`)

Answer (score 0):

Use [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) or [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) of a `String` class

```
var text = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML
           // Gentlemen, I suggest you beam me aboard.
var pos = text.indexOf('men') // 6
var men1 = text.substring(6,8+1) // men
var men2 = text.substr(6,3) // men
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var thisHTML = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML().substring(6, 9);
alert(thisHTML); // prints "men"
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to look for "men" word, right?
Here is the trick:

```
var text = document.getElementById('kirk').innerHTML;
text = text.split("men");// splitting the word into two or more parts if 'men' word exists
var check= text.length;
if (check > 1){// if the word men found
   alert("there is/are "+(check-1)+" 'men' word(s) in the text.");
}
else{
   alert("'men' word not found");
}
```

That's it!
if you use substring function, it would not be efficient because the 'men' word could be placed anywhere in the words.

Comment: Actually, "men" was meant as a location placeholder, for character positions 6, 7, and 8. I did not clarify that, so I can see how it could be interpreted as a search string. I'm leaving things as is, though, since your response is a helpful relevant extension of related functionality.

Comment: oh yes,, i just noticed it :D @Guessed .

Comment: @Guessed , of course you can use my script above to check the "men" words first. Then if it's found, you can find the first position of 'men' by using `indexOf` function.

Comment: So, you can define the substring position dinamically